# É possivel verificar se um elemento não possui o atributo style com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html-select

Eu tenho uma tabela em scroll infinito, preciso verificar se o último `<tr>` dela está **SEM** o atributo `style=display:none`. É possível verificar ?

Comment: é possível saber o valor que está definido para `display`, isso ajuda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em jQuery é possível usar

```
var visivel = $(elemento-ou-seletor).is(":visible"); 
var naoVisivel = $(elemento-ou-seletor).is(":hidden");
```

Isso verifica se o elemento tem `display: none;` ou não. Ignora a visibilidade, somente o atributo que referes. Elementos com opacidade `0` ou `visibility: hidden` não são considerados pois tecnicamente fazem parte do render da página e ocupam espaço.

Mais sobre o `:visible` aqui: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401783/8063) do [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio), você consegue verificar a última `tr` da tabela com o seletor `:last` do jQuery:

```
if($("table tr:last").is(":hidden")){
   // não está visível
}
```

Se você tiver apenas 1 tabela na página, o código acima deve funcionar. Mas é mais recomendado pegar a tabela por um id ou outro atributo que seja único da tabela, pare evitar conflito caso você tenha mais de uma tabela na página.

Por exemplo, pelo `id`:

```
<table id="tabela">
...
</table>
```

Seletor:

```
$("#tabela tr:last").is(":hidden")
```

[Documentação oficial do seletor `:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).